# error: no such column

Tags: android, sqlite

I developing an android application that uses sqlite database.

1. **Primary Issue:**
   **I keep facing this error no such column but I just cant find what is the cause to this problem. Any comments will be appreciated.**
2. **Secondary Issue:**
   I wanted the application to check whether the user's info is inside the database or not. If it doesn't exist, I want the system to work on something. How to do the checking part? I tried something like below. But I'm not sure whether it works or not because of the no such column issue.

   ```
                   String values[] = helper.get_synccontentByEmailID(SettingConstant.EMAIL);
               if(!(values[0] == null)){


               }
   ```

--Database Class--

```
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE synccontent (" + 
            "tableid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            "emailid_sync TEXT " +
            "contentid TEXT," +
            "contentpath TEXT," +
            "filesize TEXT," +
            "createdtime TEXT,"+
            "createdate TIMESTAMP default current_timestamp);");
}
public String[] get_synccontentByEmailID(String emailid_sync){
    SQLiteDatabase myDB = null;
    String[] returnMsg = null;
    myDB = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor c = myDB.rawQuery("SELECT tableid, emailid_sync, contentid, contentpath, filesize, createdtime" +
            " from synccontent where emailid_sync='"+emailid_sync+"' ", null);
    int emailid_syncColumn = c.getColumnIndex("emailid_sync");              
    int contentidColumn = c.getColumnIndex("contentid");
    int contentpathColumn = c.getColumnIndex("contentpath");
    int filesizeColumn = c.getColumnIndex("filesize");
    int createdtimeColumn = c.getColumnIndex("createdtime");

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            returnMsg = new String[5]; 
            String contentid = c.getString(contentidColumn);
            String contentpath = c.getString(contentpathColumn);
            String filesize = c.getString(filesizeColumn);
            String createdtime = c.getString(createdtimeColumn);

            returnMsg[0] = emailid_sync;
            returnMsg[1] = contentid;
            returnMsg[2] = contentpath;
            returnMsg[3] = filesize;
            returnMsg[4] = createdtime;

        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
```

--Main Activity--

```
    syncButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sync_btn);
    syncButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                    String values[] = helper.get_synccontentByEmailID(SettingConstant.EMAIL);
                if(!(values[0] == null)){


                }





E/AndroidRuntime(4543): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: contentid: , while compiling: SELECT tableid, emailid_sync, contentid, contentpath, filesize, createdtime from wbm_synccontent where emailid_sync='testing@yahoo.com'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a missing comma after `emailid_sync TEXT`.

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE synccontent (" + 
            "tableid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            "emailid_sync TEXT, " +
            "contentid TEXT," +
            "contentpath TEXT," +
            "filesize TEXT," +
            "createdtime TEXT,"+
            "createdate TIMESTAMP default current_timestamp);");
```

That should fix the primary issue, solution to secondary was given in the other answer. I think it's fine.

Comment: Hey, Thanks Binoy Babu! Didn't notice there was a missing comma that causes all these. That was really careless of me.

Comment: Yeah, it's a very common mistake.

Answer (score 1):

`Primary Issue`

Maybe you created table without contentId first.Then you added new column contentId.But table is not recreated.To recreate the table and db again uninstall the application and then install again.

```
Secondary Issue
```

You can do like this

```
Cursor c = myDB.rawQuery("SELECT * from synccontent where emailid_sync='"+emailid_sync+"' ", null);
if(c.getCount()==0){       //not in db
}
```

Comment: I tried uninstall and re-install the application, but I still having the same problem. I just don't know what's wrong here.

Comment: See your table structure using a sqlite browser.

Comment: I'll try the secondary issue's solution you provide in a moment. Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Is there another similar way to work this in main activity? I'm trying to if it is not in db, it will perform certain task at the main activity.

Comment: You can write a method that will check for it.Call the method in main activity and do accordingly.

Comment: Rasel thanks for the answers and pointers! Will vote this up once I enough reputation to do so.